# Nginx configuration for high throughput

Tags: nginx

We have tested standalone nginx in 32 core processor machine with concurrency level 100 ,500, 1000, 1500 maximum performance we got is 30K (TPS) for 1K messages.

Following are the Nginx Configurations

```
  worker_processes  auto;

    events {
        worker_connections  2048;
        use epoll;
        multi_accept on;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;



        sendfile        on;

        keepalive_timeout  6000;
        access_log off;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

            open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; 
open_file_cache_valid 30s; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;
reset_timedout_connection on;
client_body_timeout 10;
send_timeout 2;
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 10240;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\."; 



        server {
            listen       9090;
            server_name  localhost;



            location / {

             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Connection "";
             proxy_pass http://208.16.85.20:5050/service;

            }


            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }


        }
```

What are the other configurations that can be used to increase throughput and what will be the max performance of Nginx

Comment: What makes you  think that nigx is a bottleneck?

Comment: we got more throughput than nginex using another gateway for same BE in same machine